# Why does first character of a string repeat itself when finding all possible combinations of given string?

Tags: python, loops, combinations, brute-force

My question might not be clear, but I'm trying to get all possible 10 char length combinations of a string. Here is my code:

```
def printPwd(set, k):
    n = len(set)
    pwdRec(set,"", n, k)

def pwdRec(set, prefix, n, k):
    if k==0:
        print(prefix)
        return

    for i in range(n):
        nPrefix = prefix + set[i]
        nk = k-1
        pwdRec(set, nPrefix, n, nk)

chars = list("abcdefghijklmno.@-_&")
length = 10

printPwd(chars, length)
```

It outputs something like this:

```
aaaaabcde@
aaaaabcde-
aaaaabcde_
aaaaabcdfg
...
```

I'm getting five "a" and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, but an alternative: `import itertools as it; print(list(map("".join, it.permutations("abcdefghijklmno.@-_&", 10))))`. Note: might be a lenghty output, so start with a small input string and a small length.

Comment: This may be completely wrong, but I believe the issue is that when you're calling your recursive function, you're not cutting out the character of the set you just looked at. You should be calling pwdRec(set[i:], nPrefix, n, nk)

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Put a `print` statement at the top of each function to echo the input arguments; this often shows recursion errors.

Comment: @0 0, your answer gives a list of combinations. It must search all combinations before I could check if it is the right password. So If the password is in the middle then, It would have taken unecessary time. @alex067, it gives the same result. Thanks guys

Comment: You can iterate over the permutations without calculating the list, and then quit halfway (note that your question says "I'm trying to get *all* possible"; your comment changed the question). The difference is that the permutations in my comment don't re-use elements; if you want that, you could probably use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`; see the itertools documentation.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an unsatisfactory fix. You should absolutely use itertools if you just want to do this quickly and correctly. Trying to debug your original code might merit a new question.

Comment: Thanks. yea itertools is the way to go. it has a combinations method that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this answer gives the correct output but I haven't been able to figure out why it works*

The question you should be asking is not

> "why do I get five 'a's?"

But

> "Why don't I get ten 'a's?"

. The expected output from this algorithm is:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaab
aaaaaaaaac
aaaaaaaaad
aaaaaaaaae
...
```

But yours starts off

```
aaaaj@bc
aaaaaaj@bd
aaaaaaj@be
aaaaaaj@bf
```

In fact, something very worrying is happening. The output isn't even deterministic, each time I run it I get a different result! I haven't actually figured this out so commenters please assist. If I run this in debug an click through slowly I get the correct output. I can also correct the output by adding a tiny sleep into the function like so:

```
import time

def printPwd(set, k):
    n = len(set)
    pwdRec(set,"", n, k)

def pwdRec(set, prefix, n, k):
    time.sleep(0.000001)
    if k==0:
        print(prefix)
        return

    for i in range(n):
        nPrefix = prefix + set[i]
        nk = k-1
        pwdRec(set, nPrefix, n, nk) #alex067's change here plus my change


chars = list("abcdefghijklmno.@-_&")
length = 10

printPwd(chars, length)
```

It looks like we're falling foul of some kind of mutable type or non-atomic operation but I haven't yet found it.

**alex067's comment**
Making the change suggested by @alex067 appears to fix the output at first but you get out of range errors after the first two loops because your set is no longer `n` long. You also actually miss some permutations, the first of these being `aaaaaaaaba` so it's not fixed at all, but at least it's deterministic.

Comment: The suggestion by @alex067 means that for any given character in the string, the character to its right is either the same, or one which appears "later" in the list of valid characters. Hence why it doesn't produce `aaaaaaaaba`, amongst many others.

Comment: Yes indeed, I didn't have time to write this out. The odd things is that just adding the slice makes the output behave. I guess it just slows it down enough to avoid the issue

Comment: Yeah, it's a strange one to debug eh.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can think of is "Why wouldn't it?" The password cannot contain duplicates, yet nothing in your code enforces that. Instead, your program is simply producing all strings of a certain length composed from the character set.

@SimonN's remark that your output should begin with a string of 10 'a's is correct, and it does. When written to a file, the first string is indeed 'aaaaaaaaaa', which leads me to believe that the differences in output observed are purely graphical, caused by the large amount of strings printed in quick succession.

The suggestion by @alex067 doesn't solve the problem either, since not only does it still lead to duplicate characters, instead of removing just a single character once it has been used, it removes all the characters that come before it in the list. That last point means that for passwords of length 3, for example, the perfectly valid strings `acb`, `bac`, etc. are omitted. Of course, instead of `prefix[i:]` we could use `prefix[i+1:]`, but that only rids us of the former, not the latter problem.

---

As you now know, `itertools` provides what is probably the best solution, and I will cover that below. Before that, however, here is a recursive method that I find quite nice:

```py
def pwd_rec(curr_charset: str, curr_pwd: str, pwd_len: int) -> List[str]:
    result_strs = []
    for idx, curr_char in enumerate(curr_charset):
        new_pwd = curr_pwd + curr_char
        if len(new_pwd) == pwd_len:
            result_strs.append(new_pwd)
        else:
            result_strs.extend(pwd_rec(curr_charset[:idx] + curr_charset[idx+1:], new_pwd, pwd_len))
    return result_strs
```

Here is a lazier version of that method, using generators instead of lists:

```py
def pwd_rec(curr_charset: str, curr_pwd: str, pwd_len: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    for idx, curr_char in enumerate(curr_charset):
        new_pwd = curr_pwd + curr_char
        if len(new_pwd) == pwd_len:
            yield new_pwd
        else:
            yield from pwd_rec(curr_charset[:idx] + curr_charset[idx+1:], new_pwd, pwd_len)
```

---

As promised, here is a method using `itertools`:

```py
import itertools as itt

def pwd_perms(charset: str, pwd_len: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    for curr in itt.permutations(charset, pwd_len):
        yield ''.join(curr)
```

---

Let me know if you have any questions :)